# Word or phrase for someone who "throws money" at a situation, but for tech

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Just like the title says. I am looking for a word or phrase for a someone who "throws money" at a situation, but for technology. They may not know what they are doing, the underlying tech behind it, or if its the right solution. Instead, much like someone who "throws money" at a solution, trying to get it to go away (which often does not work), this person will "throw tech" at a solution to try and make it go away.

Comment: That's a "CEO", on even days.  (On odd days the CEO lays off techies because the tech strategy isn't working.)

Comment: what? that doesn't make sense/

Comment: Those people are called people with "more chips than brains".

Answer (score 1):

A general term for this is a **brute force** solution.  I don't know of a tech specific variant.